# One button to change all settings in the Wordpress theme customizer?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been attempting to create a theme reset button for the Wordpress theme customizer that automatically removes all of the theme_mod settings. I have tried multiple ways to do this and have never been able to get it to work.  [As seen here.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/problem-with-function-not-executing)

After multiple failed attempts using the remove_theme_mods approach I begin to wonder if that is my problem other than the ajax and javascript being faulty and not properly binding the button.

Since I save all defaults into one big array so when my theme is installed it automatically has values populated on the theme customizer page, and the theme has a specific look... I was thinking I could try a different approach to instead remove the theme settings I just over ride them, maybe with a custom control? Possibly by somehow assigning these default values to all settings? I really hope someone can help me get this going. If you have any ideas I would appreciate it very very much.

Here is an example of how I assign the default values for the theme:

```
function newtheme_get_theme_mods() {

$defaults = array(

        'newtheme_responsive'                 => true,

        'newtheme_hero_title'                 => 'Beautiful and Elegant',

        'newtheme_hero_description'           => 'The best theme in the world',

                'newtheme_header_logo'                => '/wp-content/themes/newtheme/img/logo.png',

                'newtheme_header_background_color'    => 'rgba(35,35,35, 0.9)'


    return $defaults;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Class Theme and store theme settings in database with the serialized object of class theme. On changing the theme or restoring the theme load that serialized object in your Theme class constructor and then the class will use the settings accordingly. That is some thing I have done with my project so far.

Comment: The theme heavily relies on theme_mod settings. Basically the whole theme is customizable through the theme customizer API and is built around that. I think it would be too much work to implement that at this stage for this feature. I will definitely go with that approach next time though.

Answer (score 0):

As answered on [Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99652/one-button-to-change-all-settings-in-theme-customizer/298765#298765)

The problem with using `remove_theme_mods` for showing defaults in the Customizer is

- the Customizer is a preview which you can exit without saving,
- the individual theme_mods are filtered, but not the entire theme_mod array
- theme_mods includes menus and widgets.

I also wanted a reset button, but I chose instead to create a Preset control, and one of the presets is "defaults". This way uses a `select`, so there is no problem with the button not working (because `bind` is for value changes and buttons don't change their values).

The trick is to use ajax to retrieve the chosen preset, and then loop over the values in javascript, assigning them to the settings so that those changes will trigger the refresh of the preview. My code includes filters so that child themes can add in more options and presets. And the presets can be subsets of the options available.

Here is **PHP for the Preset control** (just a normal `select`, but a settingless control):

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'option_presets', array(
    'label'    => __( 'Use preset theme options', 'mytheme' ),
    'description' => __( 'Theme options will be set to the preset values.', 'mytheme' ),
    'section'  => 'mytheme_section',
    'settings' => array(),
    'type'     => 'select',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'choices'  => mytheme_option_presets_choices(),
) );
```

Here is the **rest of the PHP functions**.

```
/**
 * Supply list of choices for option presets.
 */
function mytheme_option_presets_choices() {
    return apply_filters( 'mytheme_option_presets_choices', array(
        'none' => __( 'Select preset', 'mytheme' ),
        'defaults' => __( 'Defaults', 'mytheme' ),
        'dark' => __( 'Dark', 'mytheme' ),
    ) );
}

/**
 * Sanitize an option preset choice.
 */
function mytheme_sanitize_option_presets_choice( $input ) {
    $valid = mytheme_option_presets_choices();
    return array_key_exists( $input, $valid ) ? $input : 'none';
}

/**
 * Get the preset values for the chosen option preset.
 */
function mytheme_option_preset( $which ) {
    $values = array();
    if ( 'defaults' === $which ) {
        $values = mytheme_default_values();
    }
    if ( 'dark' === $which ) {
        $values = array(
            'body_textcolor' => '#f9f7f7',
            'background_color' => '#444244',
            'header_textcolor' => '#bf9a07',
            'area_classes' => array(
                'sidebar' => 'semi-black',
                'widgets' => 'box',
                ),
        );
    }
    return apply_filters( 'mytheme_option_preset', $values, $which );
}

/**
 * Add a nonce for Customizer for option presets.
 */
function mytheme_refresh_nonces( $nonces ) {
    $nonces['mytheme-customize-presets'] = wp_create_nonce( 'mytheme-customize-presets' );
    return $nonces;
}
add_filter( 'customize_refresh_nonces', 'mytheme_refresh_nonces' );

/**
 * Ajax handler for supplying option preset values.
 */
function mytheme_ajax_option_preset_values() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'mytheme-customize-presets', 'option_presets_nonce' );
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
        wp_die( -1 );
    }

    if ( empty( $_POST['option_preset'] ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error( 'mytheme_missing_preset_parameter' );
    }
    $preset = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['option_preset'] ) );
    $values = mytheme_option_preset( $preset );
    if ( empty( $values ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error( array( 'message' => __( 'No preset found.', 'mytheme' ) ) );
    }
    else {   // Flatten the array.
        foreach ($values as $key => $avalue) {
            if ( is_array( $avalue ) ) {
                unset( $values[$key] );
                foreach ($avalue as $subkey => $subvalue) {
                    $values[$key . '[' . $subkey . ']'] = $subvalue;
                }
            }
        }
        wp_send_json_success( array( 'values' => $values ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mytheme_option_preset', 'mytheme_ajax_option_preset_values' );
```

And then just a **little bit of Javascript** to make the ajax request. This is queued on the `'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts'` action. *(I left out the display of the error message.)*

```
wp.customize.control( 'option_presets', function( control ) {
    control.element = new wp.customize.Element( control.container.find( 'select' ) );
    control.element.bind( function( preset ) {
        var request = wp.ajax.post( 'mytheme_option_preset', {
            option_presets_nonce: wp.customize.settings.nonce['mytheme-customize-presets'],
            wp_customize: 'on',
            customize_theme: wp.customize.settings.theme.stylesheet,
            option_preset: preset
        } );
        request.done( function( response ) {
            _.each( response.values, function( value, id ) {
                var setting = wp.customize( id );
                if ( setting ) {
                    setting.set( value );
                }
            } );
        } );
    } );
} );
```